# How to insert an array into a hidden input in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a table that contains rows. each rows have their own attribute called as `data`. I want to put all tr into a hidden input type. how can I do that?
I want to get the `$('#valuePermission').val()` in the server-side.

```
<form >
   <input type="hidden" name="valuePermission[]" id="valuePermission" value=""/>


<table class='table table-hover table-striped'>
  <tr data="1+a"><td>name:1</td><td>type:a</td></tr>
  <tr data="2+b"><td>name:2</td><td>type:b</td></tr>
  <tr data="3+c"><td>name:3</td><td>type:c</td></tr>
</table>
 <button type="submit" id="btn">submit</button>
</form>
<script>
  $('#btn').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var dt=[];
      $('table').find('tr').each(function(){
          dt.push($(this).attr('data')); 
      });
$('#valuePermission').val(dt);
  });
$('form').submit();
</script>
```

in server-side I want to have sth like this:

```
<?php $var=$_POST['valuePermission'];
if(isset($var && !empty($var))

    $var=json_decode($var);
foreach($var as $v=>$k)
    echo $v;
?>
```

the results is like this:
`*5+sport+500001+soccer,*5+sport+500002+vollyball,*5+sport+500003+swimming,*5+sport+500004+running,*5+sport+500006+tenis,*5+sport+500007+table tenis`
I want to have sth like this:
`array[0]='5+sport+500001+soccer'
 array[1]='5+sport+500001+vollyball` and ....

Comment: Join the array with some delemiter and split again at server

Answer (score 3):

Pass it as json string **[`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)** can be used for that, then from server side decode it and use . Also prevent the default click event action(here form submission) otherwise form get submitted before hidden field value is updating, use **[`event.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)** for that. At last submit form using code.

```
<form >
   <input type="hidden" name="valuePermission" id="valuePermission" value=""/>


<table class='table table-hover table-striped'>
  <tr data="1+a"><td>name:1</td><td>type:a</td></tr>
  <tr data="2+b"><td>name:2</td><td>type:b</td></tr>
  <tr data="3+c"><td>name:3</td><td>type:c</td></tr>
</table>
 <button type="submit" id="btn">submit</button>
</form>
<script>
  $('#btn').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var dt=[];
      $('table').find('tr').each(function(){
          dt.push($(this).attr('data')); 
      });
$('#valuePermission').val(JSON.stringify(dt));
  $(this).closest('form').submit();
  });
</script>
```

Server side use **[`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)** to decode the json string

```
<?php $var = json_decode($_POST['valuePermission']);
foreach($var as $v=>$k)
    echo $v;
?>
```

---

**UPDATE :**

The another method that you can try is create multiple hidden input

```
<form>
  <input type="hidden" name="valuePermission[]" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="valuePermission[]" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="valuePermission[]" value="" />


  <table class='table table-hover table-striped'>
    <tr data="1+a">
      <td>name:1</td>
      <td>type:a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data="2+b">
      <td>name:2</td>
      <td>type:b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data="3+c">
      <td>name:3</td>
      <td>type:c</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="button" id="btn">submit</button>
</form>
<script>
  $('#btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $input = $('name="valuePermission[]"');
    return $('table').find('tr').each(function(i) {
      $input.eq(i).val($(this).attr('data'));
    })
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @Pravan C Balan. I did it `json_decode` but it doesn't get the value.
if I use `json.stringify` , it returns me sth like this: `[a+1,b+2,c+3]` but I want sth like this `array[0]='a+1', array[1]='b+2',..

Comment: @Pravan C Balan. I use `json_decode` but it sets uninitialized array. without `json_decode` it shows me an array[] but with wrong vlaue

Comment: @hilaryclinton : in first method you need to remove `[]` from name it should be `name="valuePermission"` otherwise use `json_decode($_POST['valuePermission'][0]);` in server

Comment: @hilaryclinton : check second method with the multiplr input field

Comment: @Pravan C Balan. my problem is all the `data` of each tr is inserted into array[0]. I have 500 tr and each of them has the value that contains `+` to split and get them.I want to loop through the array like array[0], array[1],...

Comment: @hilaryclinton : can you share the printed value `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: @Pravan C Balan. I use `var_dump` but it just shows me an empty array. but if I use `input type ="hidden" name="...[]" it shows me but all attributes inside in array[0]

Comment: @hilaryclinton : you need to set `method` attribute `<form method="POST">`

Comment: @hilaryclinton : also try `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`

Comment: @Pravan C Balan. I set it `method='post'` but for writing briefly I didn't mention it

Comment: @hilaryclinton : I think the form is getting submitted before updating the input field.... I've updated the click event handle .. please check

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use input name `valuePermission` instead of `valuePermission[]`, also use form action and method

```
<form id="myform" action="target.php" method="post" >
<input type="hidden" name="valuePermission" id="valuePermission" value=""/>


<table class='table table-hover table-striped'>
  <tr data="1+a"><td>name:1</td><td>type:a</td></tr>
  <tr data="2+b"><td>name:2</td><td>type:b</td></tr>
  <tr data="3+c"><td>name:3</td><td>type:c</td></tr>
</table>
<button type="submit" id="btn">submit</button>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#btn').click(function(){
          var dt='';
          $('.table').find('tr').each(function(){
              if(dt == '')
              {
                dt = $(this).attr('data');
              }
              else
              {
                dt+='*'+$(this).attr('data');
              }
          });
          if($('#valuePermission').val(dt))
          {
            $( "#myform").submit();
          }

      }); 
});
</script>
```

In target file

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['valuePermission']))
{   
    $var = explode('*',$_POST['valuePermission']);
    foreach($var as $k => $v)
    {
        echo $v;
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

**Modified for explode**

```
$str = '*5+sport+500001+soccer,*5+sport+500002+vollyball,*5+sport+500003+swimming,*5+sport+500004+running,*5+sport+500006+tenis,*5+sport+500007+table tenis';
$str = explode('*',$str);

$newArray =array();
foreach(array_filter($str) as $val)
{
    $newArray[] = trim($val,',');
}   
echo "<pre>"; print_r($newArray);
```

This will give you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5+sport+500001+soccer
    [1] => 5+sport+500002+vollyball
    [2] => 5+sport+500003+swimming
    [3] => 5+sport+500004+running
    [4] => 5+sport+500006+tenis
    [5] => 5+sport+500007+table tenis
)
```

Comment: Barmala. `tr` are dynamically added or removed. so I want to handle it when the user is sure to submit the value of the table , I need the values of the table.

Comment: Barmala. I edit my script. I prevent from submitting the form. after assign the dataTable into the hidden field , then I submit the form

Comment: Barmala. is there any way to explode`($var=explode('*',$_POST['valuePermission'])` instead of sth you writed

Comment: now what you are getting in `$_POST` on php file ?? @hilaryclinton

Comment: Barmala. I use just $_post[] instead of `json_decode($_post[])`. I just get an array with a very very long data sth like this: array.length =10000
as I asked you, in this array there are data that contain `,` inside them. but the functionality goes wrong. because when it reaches into this value like `video, music, sport` it separates it as 3 values.

Comment: just use this `echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST['valuePermission']); die;` on php page where your page is submitted and see output..

Comment: @hilaryclinton, I've modified the script code and add id to form, now our form is submitted only when value is set in hidden filed.. take a look at code and use the same

Comment: @hilaryclinton, I've changed now separate the  with `*` instead of `,`

Comment: Barmala. I add the results and explain what I want to have. thx

Comment: Barmala. As I said before I have this array like this: array[0]='movie,music,rock'. I insist to use it because this is just one category and not array[0]='movie', array[1]='music', array[2]='rock'. is it clear? when I use `*` delimiter, but the problem is still remained

Comment: @hilaryclinton sorry dear, nothing is clear to me... In which format you have data and what you want ??

Comment: Barmala. what if I have a unique row of an array that contains `,`?. it's clear that it will be exploded to the several rows whereas it must be kept as one row. If you have `array[0]='movie,music,rock`, it is not correct to split them into several rows, because they are acceptable if all come together .thx

Comment: but now I'm using `*` to explode that row ... @hilaryclinton, then where is the problem..?

Comment: Barmala. if your str would be sth like this, how do you handle the `,` between your array?  `$str=*5+sport+500001+soccer,*5+sport+500002+vollyball,table tenis,tenis`. I mean if you want to show `vollybal,table tenis, tenis as a unique value , how do y handle it?thx

Comment: do you want `vollyball,table tenis,tenis` or `5+sport+500002+vollyball,table tenis,tenis` as a unique value...

Comment: Barmala.let me clarify it to you. I have many categories which  have their children and each children has it's child and so on. inside them , there are several categories which their value consist of string that has `,` inside it . but the problem occurs when this specific item is going to explode and the machine thinks the unique value is multi-part value and splits it as 3 or more parts whereas I don't want it as a separated part